# Wireless Mouse/Keyboard Seem to slow down my machine | Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, keyboard, mouse

I recently got a wireless mouse and keyboard and tried using them, however after so may minutes (15-20) I notice a very abrupt plummet in performance.

Web Pages take forever to load up, the mouse seems to click where I do not click (example: I clicked on the address bar only for it to instead refresh the webpage, I clicked on the address bar multiple times to see if this was just a one time thing - it wasn't).

The keyboard seems to also mis-type what I ask it to after this duration of time (15-20 mins as said).

I am hard wired into the Internet, so I can't really see how WIFI would interfere with the receiver.

My PC loads websites and everything else in a very timely manner (a few seconds) when I have my wired mouse and keyboard hooked up.

Comment: please clarify: your whole computer slows down? one app slows down? internet speed slows down? only mouse and keyboard are delayed? What other wierless devices are near you?

Comment: My entire machine seems to. As for other wireless devices, I keep my cell near by which is an android. I also have a cordless/wireless home phone. Just as well, I'd assume that there are wireless signals in nearby me as I live in an apartment.

Comment: an entire machine slow down seems weird... Do try opening task manager when you connect the wierless devices and see if cpu usage goes to 100%. If it does, report the task that's causing it

Comment: What does 'reporting a task' do?

Comment: report the task to us. To do this, open task manager by holding ctrl+shift+escape. Then select the "processes" tab, then click the "cpu" heading. It will now sort items by amount of cpu time. Tell us if one task is always at the top of the list. Also, check overall cpu usage in the "performance" tab

Answer (score -2):

This "wireless keyboard and mouse seem to slow down my computer" is legit and is caused by Microsoft's antimalware and protection software, simultaneously, kick in and try to protect the device from unknown software (or hardware, in this example).

This is similar to how an unsecured USB leads to the same result. In my experience, with a wired mouse my CPU is a normal 30%, but with a wireless mouse and with antimalware and Windows protections running my CPU would pass the 100% in a flash.

I hope this helped you. Remember to carefully choose your third-party hardware manufacturers like Logitech and Razer(in my case the mouse was only for $5).